# JMeter - Extract Form's action attribute using Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: regex, forms, jmeter, expression, extractor

In JMeter, using a post processor Regular Expression Extractor, i want to extract the form's action attribute. What regular expression should i use?

Answer (score 1):

You [should not be using regular expression to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), go for [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead and use query like

```
//form/@action
```

See [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the XPath Extractor to work; from reading the JMeter log, it looks like the XPath Extractor will not work if the html being parsed is not well-formed xml.

But, I was able to extract the form action using a CSS Selector Extractor with the following values:

- CSS Selector expression: form
- Attribute: action
- Match No. (0 for Random): 1

Comment: You can tick the "Use Tidy (tolerant parser)" option to get around this